# Keras ResNet -- Val acc not improving, val loss fluctuates, even data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

Validation accuracy stays constant after ever epoch; however, the validation loss fluctuates. The model is hyper overfitting at the moment with a training accuracy of ~90% after 3-4 epochs. The current validation accuracy is around the % of random guessing for the higher percentage class.

Tensorflow Version: 1.14.0

Hyperparameter / other configs:
--Images augmented with shifts / reflections
--Pretrained weights (ImageNet)
--Changed top layers to include BatchNorm and Dropout
--About 5000 training images, 1000 validation images, properly shuffled
--Softmax classification (binary, 2 classes)
--Labels are correct
--Learning rates values tried: 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001
--RMSProp optimizer
--Categorical cross-entropy (log loss)
--Class weights applied proportional to the amount of data in each class (and there isn't much of an imbalance to begin with...)

Code:

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(128,128,3))
finetune_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])
history = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_data, validation_data=valid_data, epochs=100, class_weight=class_weights, shuffle=True, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Here's the code for the layers that use BatchNorm and Dropout:

```
output = Dense(layer_size, name = 'Dense_{}'.format(i))(output)
output = BatchNormalization()(output)
output = Activation("relu")(output)
output = Dropout(0.5)(output)

predictions = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(output)
finetune_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

To give you all some idea of the output (sorry, it is a nightmare for me to run on my machine, but it basically exhibits the same behavior even when I test past 25 epochs):

```
Epoch 1/100
149/149 [==============================] - 356s 2s/step - loss: 0.7069 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7681 - val_loss: 2.4147 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 2/100
149/149 [==============================] - 387s 3s/step - loss: 0.4370 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8465 - val_loss: 1.0831 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 3/100
149/149 [==============================] - 364s 2s/step - loss: 0.3708 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8707 - val_loss: 0.7329 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 4/100
149/149 [==============================] - 383s 3s/step - loss: 0.3355 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8898 - val_loss: 0.7157 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 5/100
149/149 [==============================] - 332s 2s/step - loss: 0.2776 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9075 - val_loss: 0.6897 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 6/100
149/149 [==============================] - 349s 2s/step - loss: 0.2287 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9220 - val_loss: 0.6855 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 7/100
149/149 [==============================] - 326s 2s/step - loss: 0.2196 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9319 - val_loss: 0.7273 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 8/100
149/149 [==============================] - 331s 2s/step - loss: 0.1782 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9451 - val_loss: 0.8641 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 9/100
149/149 [==============================] - 319s 2s/step - loss: 0.1774 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9466 - val_loss: 0.8990 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
Epoch 10/100
149/149 [==============================] - 331s 2s/step - loss: 0.1653 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9495 - val_loss: 0.9257 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5529
```

I'd like to try to decrease my validation loss and address the constant accuracy problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried augmenting training data?

Comment: look at confusion matrix

Comment: @alexey, yep. I've slapped in random augmentations e.g. reflections, shifts, etc.

Comment: 1. Please include version of Tensorflow and Keras. 
   Reason: Keras\Tensorflow in one of the versions have a bug with BatchNormalization.
 2. Describe what is the data in general. What is the batch size? How do you read the data? How the data is arranged? How many classes are there?
3. Maybe some augmentations don't make sense in your case and influence the results of the validation. 4. Maybe the amount of data you have is not enough. The first results you show us are at the end of Epoch 1, after the model has trained on 149 batches. What is the starting point of the model?

Comment: @Ben thanks for the edit suggestion -- silly typo on my end. I've updated the version number. 
(2)
(i) Batch size: 32
(ii) Data is read through Keras' flow_from_dir / ImageDataGenerator
(iii) Data is shuffled, I've mentioned that there are 2 classes (binary)
(iv) Simple augmentations, yes they do make sense... the ones that I put in should hypothetically move both the training & validation metrics towards each other
(v) Starting point as in weights? Pre-trained imagenet weights as I've mentioned.

A lot of the relevant code is shown and other than that, other things are described.

Comment: @LeehoLim I guess you made test to be sure dropout/ batch norm, all other modification... increase performance right? I think you should really look at confusion matrix and heat map activation (https://medium.com/@suraggupta17/an-introduction-to-computer-vision-using-transfer-learning-in-fast-ai-aircraft-classification-a2685d266ac?source=email-94ae2eadc24c-1565837892902-digest.reader------0-58------------------f29dcad6_bef8_46f6_9c16_b14f70b50968-1-----&sectionName=top) to try to figure why it doesnt work

Comment: Yes. I've taken a look at the confusion matrix as well. I did test each modification as I added them on. I actually ended up finding the culprit... REALLY SILLY MISTAKE!!

Comment: @LeehoLim for curisority, what was the problem?

Comment: @akhetos I had originally frozen a few layers to tweak for hyperparameters and did not unfreeze them... got the val_acc to around 85%!